# php Regex match all text inside apostrophes

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, apostrophe

Here is the string: `WHERE CLASS = 'CARL-01' OR CLASS = 'CARL-03' OR CLASS = 'CARL-04' OR CLASS =''`

I need a regex function that will match the below probably using `preg_match` via php:

```
CARL-01
CARL-03
CARL-04
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

```
preg_match_all('/\'([^\']+)\'/', $string, $matches);
$matches = $matches[1];
```

Comment: This did it, I had initially used `preg_match` instead of `preg_match_all`, thank you